# How to rotate JLabel to upright position

Tags: java, swing, charts, jpanel, jlabel

I designing a chart and used JLabels for the graph data points. Since I'm creating the JLabels Dynamically and adding it to the JPanel. The base of the JLabels are up whilst the height goes down, making it look like an upside down chart. What can I do to display it upright? I used NullLayout for the JPanel
[image]

```
for (int n = 0; n < 500; n++) {
        int rnd = rd.nextInt(190 - 1 + 1) + 1;
  ImageIcon      imageIcon3 = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon("bkground.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(2, rnd, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        jPanel2.add(graphChild[n]);
        graphChild[n].setSize(2, rnd);
        graphChild[n].setLocation(tyu, 50);
        graphChild[n].setIcon(imageIcon3);
        tyu = tyu + 3;
    }
```

Comment: You should consider using another color for the background and chart, they have little contrast to each other and makes it hard to see it. As for the rest, consider posting a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

> I used NullLayout for the JPanel

Don't use a null layout. Instead you can use a horizontal `BoxLayout`.

Then for each component you add to the panel you can set the vertical alignment to the bottom of the panel using the setAlignmentY(…) property. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information and examples.